# NullPointerException (probably caused by getStringExtra or getTimeInstance)

Tags: android, crash, nullpointerexception

I extend BroadcastReceiver:

```
 public class MyBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (null == bundle)
            return;
        String phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
        String currentTimeString = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT).format(new Date());
        int a = 2; 
        if (currentTimeString.length() == 5) {
            a = 3;
        }
        String minutes = currentTimeString.substring(a);
        if (phoneNumber.equals(minutes)) {
            //some code
        }
    }
 }
```

I got following crash report using ACRA from one of my users (so, I cannot repeat this error):

```
"java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver myapp.service.MyBroadcast: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2144)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1114)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4389)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at myapp.service.MyBroadcast.onReceive(MyBroadcast.java:31)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2103)
    ... 10 more
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at myapp.service.MyBroadcast.onReceive(MyBroadcast.java:31)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2103)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1114)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4389)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)"
```

So, there is NullPointerException in line 31:

```
if (phoneNumber.equals(minutes)) {
```

As I understand one of strings `phoneNumber` or `minutes` is null. And as I anderstand `intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER)` cannot be null in my case (or I'm wrong?). I assume that `currentTimeString` has length 4 or 5 symbols (because it returns 1:45 or 20:54 for example). Maybe the reason is that user, who met this error has locale en_PK (Pakistan - as I think) and `DateFormat.getTimeInstance` returns time in some strange format, but as I see there should be [nothing strange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_in_Pakistan)...

What caused this `NullPointerException`?

Comment: have you set the permission for the OUTGOING CALL in your manifest file..?

Comment: @Puru of course) `android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS`

Comment: I couldn't say exactly without trying it myself but IMHO you shouldn't be using a "substring" approach for displaying time. Go for SimpleDateFormat http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly `phoneNumber` is null, as doing `String.equals(null)` would just return false. According to [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL), receivers of `ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL` may modify the number, including setting it to null if it's not supposed to be called (e.g. parental control apps). So I'd assume it was the case of your user, i.e. your receiver got a nullified number.

BTW as @Puru mentioned, your way of extracting minutes is not recommended.